# A regex that will capture all text after a colon but ends with a comma - within can be nested brackets, commas etc

Tags: java, json, string

I am trying to redact something that log4j is overriding in general. To do this, I am trying to change a regex to ensure it captures what I need...an example...

```
"definition":{"schema":{"columns":[{"dataType":"INT","name":"column_a","description":"description1"},{"dataType":"INT","name":"column_b","description":"description2"}]}}}, "some other stuff": ["SOME_STUFF"], etc.
```

Hoping to capture just...

```
{"schema":{"columns":[{"dataType":"INT","name":"column_a","description":"*** REDACTED ***"},{"dataType":"INT","name":"column_b","description":"description"}]}}}
```

I have this...

```
(?<=("definition":{))(\\.|[^\\])*?(?=}})
```

Where if I keep adding a } at the end it will keep highlighting what I need. The problem is that there is no set number of nested elements in the list.

Is there anyway to adjust the above so I can capture everything within the outer brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have other brackets after the last one you're trying to match, this regex should work for you:

```
(?<=\"definition\":)\{.*\}(?:\})
```

The main difference is moving the brackets from the lookarounds to the matching part.

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/gO1Ofw/1).

Comment: Could this be different in java? I get this error `Illegal repetition near index 25` which is due to `))`

Comment: You need to escape some characters in java, I'll update the answer right away.

Comment: Thanks! What did you mean by this...
"If you don't have other brackets after the last one you're trying to match" - there will be things before and after this text - from what I can tell, it should work against the real string but not sure if I understanding what you meant (and if it will unexpected issues)

Comment: For that sentence I meant "if that one is the last curly bracket in the text you're matching against". The reason why I asked is that `.*` will match any character, including curly brackets, so if you happen to have other curly brackets after the one you've pointed at, the match would mess up.

Comment: I think this works with the consideration but for some reason in Java it doesn't capture the last bracket - do you know why there would be a distinction?

Comment: I know why, that's my fault. I copied a wrong version of this regex. Last capturing group should have the lookaround `?:` instead of `?=` as made in the fiddle, otherwise the regex will not match it. I've just updated the solution here on Stack Overflow, should work well for you.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you if you cannot use a proper JSON parser:

```bash
(?<=\"definition\":).+?\}(?=,\h*\")
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qtdxug/2)

**Breakdown:**

- `(?<=\"definition\":)`: Lookbehind condition to make sure we have `"definition":` before the current position
- `.+?\}`: Match 1+ of any characters ending with `}`
- `(?=,\h*\")`: Lookahead to assert that we have a comma then 0 or more spaces followed by a `"` ahead of the current position

In Java use this regex declaration:

```
String regex = "(?<=\"definition\":).+?\\}(?=,\\h*\")";
```

Comment: Thank you! It's weird - your first regex seems to work but doesn't capture the last `}` when I'm testing in Intellij. The latest one doesn't work ... not sure why :( I may go with the original and account for the additional bracket

Comment: Sorry what is first regex? There is only one regex here in my answer.

Comment: Sorry that was meant for the other answer. This seems like it should work like the other one but for some reason in Java the last bracket isn't captured - do you know why that might be the case?

Comment: Check my updated answer for Java regex declaration